# Is it possible to make the controls for an audio element appear/disappear on a click event?

Tags: html, html5-audio

I'm setting the src of an audio object at runtime as follows

```
<a style="padding-top:0" href="#" onclick="audioClick('audio1', 'http://theurl.mp3');">
<p><audio id="audio1" controls></audio></p>

function audioClick(id, clip) {
    var audio = document.getElementById(id);
    if (audio.paused) {
        audio.src = clip;
        audio.play();
    }
    else {
        audio.pause();
        audio.currentTime = 0;
    }
}
```

However when the page loads the control bar says "Cannot play audio". This goes away when the audioClick() function gets displayed, however I don't want it to appear there in the first place.

Hence is there a way I can initially hide the controls, then add/remove them in the audioClick() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the controls attribute after the click, so initially you won't see the player. When your audioClick function gets called, then you can show or hide them at will using the [setAttribute()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp) and [removeAttribute()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeattribute.asp) APIs of any HTMLDOMElement.

You can see if this is what you need in this [jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbalsas/tQevu/2/)